# I can't add a variable into WebRequest in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am trying to do a searching application like sociall.net in c# console.

My purpose is , i will get a name and surname from user , and my application will search this name and surname on Google.

i tried this code :

```
        Console.WriteLine("What's your name?.");
        string name;
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        string surname;
        Console.WriteLine("What's your surname?");
        surname = Console.ReadLine();
        string site;
        site = "Http://google.com=q'name'+'surname'";

        WebRequest talep = HttpWebRequest.Create(site);
        WebResponse cevap = talep.GetResponse();
        StreamReader oku = new StreamReader(cevap.GetResponseStream());
        string Kodlar = oku.ReadToEnd();
        int baslangic = Kodlar.IndexOf("<p>") + 4;
        int bitis = Kodlar.Substring(baslangic).IndexOf("</p>");

        Console.WriteLine(Kodlar.Substring(baslangic, bitis));
        Console.Read();
```

But i get an error message like this :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll
```

What can i do for my dreams? :)

Comment: Which line throws that exception?

Comment: This line sir : WebRequest talep = HttpWebRequest.Create(site);

Comment: Your URI is malformed. Do something like `site = $"Http://google.com/#q={name}+{surname}";`

Comment: How can i fix it sir. Do you have an idea about this problem?

Comment: Thank you @CraigSelbert im trying..

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what it is trying to tell you is that your URL is not valid.

Your capturing of name and surname in the console looks correct, but the variables are not being evaluated when you construct the url.

I think instead of:

```
site = "Http://google.com=q'name'+'surname'";
```

You should try:

```
site = String.Format("https://www.google.com/?q={0}+{1}", name, surname);
```

The following should work as well:

```
site = String.Format("https://www.google.com/#q={0}+{1}", name, surname);
```

String.Format is a useful way to insert the values of variables into a string.
Of course if you didn't want to use that you can also use the basic form as follows:

```
site = "https://www.google.com/#q=" + name + "+" + surname;
```